# How to make a changeable color constant for editor materials?

Tags: unity

Due to the nature of a project I'm working on, the models I got have a bunch of redundant materials on them. I have to fiddle around with some of the colors, but every time I want to change the colors, I have to change each material to the exact same color.

Is there any way to declare some kind of swatch that I can *change* and have those changes just apply to the materials or anywhere else? For instance, in code, you'd just make a `readonly Color mainColor`, that you'd use wherever you need and could change at will. I'm looking for this kind of behavior in the **editor** itself.

Answer (score 1):

If the materials are entirely redundant, it might be best to apply a single material to all of the models, and then delete all of the other redundant materials.

If they are different enough to make it worth changing each one individually, you could write an editor extension that takes a single color and a list of materials as inputs, and then applies that color to all the materials in the list. If you need help writing an editor extension, check out Brackey's YouTube video on the topic.

Comment: Some are entirely redundant and some are not (most of them have different normal maps too). On top of that, I'm not personally working on the main model itself and I still might get an occasional iteration or different version, so I can't just remap the materials. I guess I'll have to make an extension. I just figured I'd ask, since it seemed like a pretty useful and simple feature that could likely already exist.